# How to get data between controller action and post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I'm using asp.net mvc,
I have a POST Method that called from an outside service(differnet domain) and i want when it called to get data from my site.

Before the method was called I tried to save that data in Session object and in a Cookie,
But the data is not there.

Maybe it could be because the post request sent from a different domain?

What am I doing wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Callback(Callback callback)
{
  Not Working -> 
    var userMail = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Current")["UserMail"];  
}

public ActionResult SomeSitePage()
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("Current");
    var userMail = (Session["user"] as ApplicationUser).Email;
    cookie["UserMail"] = userMail;
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you write code, where you call post method?

Comment: This method is called from another server, a payment site that call this method when a payment is complete, I don't have the call code

Comment: service that calls the method, can be written not correctly. I want to look at this code, if possible

Comment: sorry i don' t have the code, but i know this method is called with the right parameters.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you take the value from Session and assign it to a cookie and then read the value from the cookie? Could you read it directly from Session in the callback?

Comment: I didn't do both,  I tried session or cookie, and in both ways it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Apparently If a post method is called from another domain,
saving data in session or cookies does not count,
I needed to save it in the database first and then pull it out in the post method.